# Is good practice for use data params to keep json data instead of ajax call?

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I used to keep my component data inside element's data param.

Is this good or i should use ajax call to retrieve data.

**1. By data param:**

```
 <a href="#" data-core="{JSON-data}" id="item-1">
 <a href="#" data-core="{JSON-data}" id="item-2">
 <a href="#" data-core="{JSON-data}" id="item-3">
 <a href="#" data-core="{JSON-data}" id="item-4">
```

Here, all data's are **STATIC**.

**2. By Ajax:**

```
 <a href="#" id="item-1">
 <a href="#" id="item-2">
 <a href="#" id="item-3">
 <a href="#" id="item-4">
```

**jQuery:**  (Just example)

```
  $('#item-^').on('click', function()){
      // Action to Get data.
  });
```

Which one is good ?

[ Also here "**JSON-data**", might be in big in data size. ]

Comment: The data is static you say. How static is the HTML that hosts it? If that is also static, then this will work very well with caches. If the HTML changes all the time, you are needlessly sending static data repeatedly along with it. I guess Option 3 is to have a static JS or text file that is loaded separately (and can be cached).

Comment: why not create a file with a array of values and append each value a unique id that you will append to the data attribute , and based on that unique value retrieve the corresponding record

Comment: @Thilo, i mean the word STATIC is, the entire content is not need to get from server again. While i implement for-each, i'll load all necessary data to it. My question is, this process is good or not.

Comment: @madalin ivascu, Yah, right. But its also similar and very compact on access. Is there any difference on load with separate element Vs separat JSON ?

Comment: If the quantity of data is large but the user isn't likely to click many of the anchors then it is probably better to just load what they need as they need it, to speed up initial page load. But "better" is subjective...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the situation you are.

You can go for **data param**:

- If all the data is not depend on the input from the user ie in simple words static
- if you want to reduce multiple request to server.
- It increase the responsiveness means you can deliver the content without a wait for data to load

You can go for **ajax**:

- If data require some inputs or interactions from the user that is
  dynamic in nature.
- If you want to load page faster ie, you can load page without loading
  all data initially
- You can dynamically change the behavior or visual appearance if you prefer using ajax
  .

Comment: Sounds Good, 
what about "[ Also here "JSON-data", might be in big in data size. ]" ??

Comment: Updated . there is no problem with data size but the initial loading time may increased